# How to limit Hard Drive Disk I/O when reading/writing a file on disk?

Tags: windows, io, rust, hard-drive

I have a few Rust programs that read data from a file, do some operations, and write data on another file. 
Simple enough, but I've been having a big issue in that my programs saturate the HDD max I/O  and can only be executed when no other process is in use.

To be more precise, I'm currently using BufReader and BufWriter with a buffer size of 64 KB which is fantastic in and of itself to read/write a file as quickly as possible. But reading at 250MB/s and writing at the same time at 250MB/s has a tendency to overflow what the HDD can manage. Suffice to say that I'm all for speed and whatnot, but I realized that those Rust programs are asking for too much resources from the HDD and seems to be stalled by the Operating System (Windows) to let other processes work in peace. The files I'm reading/writing are generally a few Gigabytes

Now I know I could just add some form of wait() between each read/write operation on the disk but, I don't know how to find out at which speed I'm currently reading/writing and am looking for a more optimal solution. Plus even after reading the docs, I still can't find an option on BufReader/BufWriter that could limit HDD I/O operations to some arbitrary value (let's say 100MB/s for example).

I looked through the sysinfo crate but it does not seem to help in finding out current and maximum I/O for the HDD.

Am I out of luck and should I delve deeper in systems programming to find a solution ? Or is there already something that might teach how to prioritize my calls to the HDD or to simply limit my calls to some arbitrary value calculated from the currently available I/O rate of the HDD ?

Comment: May be something useful in here: https://superuser.com/questions/136021/how-to-change-i-o-priority-of-a-process-or-thread-in-win7

Comment: Quite interesting, if I understood correctly it's pretty much like a configuration that's set by calling an API with the correct parameters (here is a rust link for those that wonder : https://docs.rs/ntapi/0.3.1/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/ntapi/ntpsapi/type.NtSetInformationProcess.html). Prioritizing my I/O calls to the HDD seems feasible that way but I still can't understand how to pick a specific speed at which I can read/write from the disk without bothering too much the other processes that are running at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a bit more on the subject, apart from trying to read/write a lot of data and calculate from its performance, it seems like you can't find out HDD max I/O rate during the execution of the program and can only guess a constant at which HDD I/O rate can't go higher. (see https://superuser.com/questions/795483/how-to-limit-hdd-write-speed-for-chosen-programs/795488#795488)

But, you can still monitor disk activity, and with the number guessed earlier, you can use `wait()` more accurately than always limiting yourself at a constant speed. (here is a crate for Rust : https://github.com/myfreeweb/systemstat).

Prioritizing the process with the OS might be overkill since I'm trying to slip between other processes and share whatever resources are available at that time.